# Displaying list of data from online text file in Android App Inventor

Tags: android, list, app-inventor

I'm trying to create a little weather app for  home weather station. The weather station outputs a .txt file on an ongoing basis and I'm trying to make an android application using app inventor to read the data in the file and display it appropriately.

File is located here: http://uregina.ca/~hodder2k/realtime.txt

I am able to load the entire string into the application, but I haven't figured out a way to read and label certain columns of data within the file (ex. temperature etc).

Can this be done in App Inventor? Or should I try and switch to using the Android SDK?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to parse the result you get for the information you need
see this example of a simple parse procedure

[image]

see also here http://puravidaapps.com/info.php#parse